# Gallery center-locked horizontally scrolling

Tags: android, image-gallery

How do remove center-locked horizontally scrolling in the gallery images?

Comment: I never managed to get satisfactory results with the gallery control.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to remove center-locking with Gallery widget. Check this SO post for a detailed discussion on this topic: [How can I make a horizontal ListView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877040/how-can-i-make-a-horizontal-listview-in-android)