# What's the difference between HorizontalScrollView & ViewPager?

Tags: android

I'm new programming in Android and i have many doubts about what type of classes can i use in my first app.

I want to do a level menu like cut the rope or angry birds. Only a title and a slider menu.

I think that can do with the two classes, but I'm not sure which is better, can you tell me  the difference and which is better to use?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ViewPager allows you to flip between pages of data (between views). You supply an adapter to generate the pages that the view shows.

But HorizontalScrollView is a container for other views that you can scrolled through, allowing it to be larger than the physical display.

I would go with horizontal scroll view.

**EDIT :** See FoamyGuy's answer in [Angry Birds like scrolling menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340207/angry-birds-like-scrolling-menu) where he exactly explains how to achieve such effect.