# How to get overlapping Gallery items?

Tags: android

I have a Gallery with several items in it, and I'm trying to get them positioned so that you can see the edge of the next item. Much like this:

[image: http://imgur.com/mtQvX]

Any help on how exactly I would go about positioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sort of depends on how far you want to go with it. It should be possible to do with a simple ScrollView that you add a custom view that holds all the components in the picture you linked.

Here's what your custom layout could look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="340dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="29"
            android:textColor="#ffff0000"
            android:textSize="24dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="of 30"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="August 24 8:01 AM"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bruce Pearl&apos;s Show-Cause Pentalty And What It Means For His Coaching Future"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this looks something like

[image]

Beyond that, if you wanted to do things like make it snap to the edges of your custom views, or something like that, then you might want to look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877040/how-can-i-make-a-horizontal-listview-in-android) and [here](http://blog.velir.com/index.php/2010/11/17/android-snapping-horizontal-scroll/).