# Horizontal ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make a horizontal ListView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877040/how-can-i-make-a-horizontal-listview-in-android)

I have used Vertical ListView Many Times but for certain requirements I want  to implement the Horizontal ListView, Also list Items will come dynamically.Please help me to get the horizontal Listview.

Comment: What would be the items in your ListView? Maybe you need a ViewPager instead?

Comment: In horizontal ListView I want On top TextView & below that image

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Android API seems to be lacking a `Horizontal ListView` widget.

So In other tutorials, developer are implemented it using `Gallery` or `HorizontalScrolllView`.

Actually Gallery is make it easy because you can use Adapter with it so at runtime you can add custom view in it. And it look likes a Horizontal ListView.

Just go through the below link,

In all possible way this would be recommended [Android Horizontal ListView](https://github.com/dinocore1/DevsmartLib-Android)

Also this SO question [How can I make a horizontal ListView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877040/how-can-i-make-a-horizontal-listview-in-android)

Comment: ok,This is fine but here are values hardcoded but in my case values will come dynamically

Comment: Just add Your dynamically data in adapter then set it to HorizontialListView. It works as like a ListView just add data to adapter dynamically and set to listview at runtime also call notifyDataSetChanged() to adapter.

Comment: using dev-smart horizontal listview with an adapter and notifyDataSetChanged working like a charm .

Comment: try this http://indrapatel.blogspot.in/2013/10/horizontal-listview-in-android.html

Comment: The link in the original reply has broken, content can now be found at: http://dev-smart.com/horizontal-listview/.