# How do I implement such a layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

Photos in this layout can be swiped left and right, and swipe should be 'intelligent', like switching between photos and NOT like just horizontal scrolling of photos.

2 implementations that come to my mind:

1. HorizontalScrollView (but swiping is dumb)
2. ViewPager (but there is no way to see adjacent photos)

So, basicly I need a ViewPager for photos that can show adjacent photos.
Is there a robust solution for this?

[image: Layout]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [TwoWayView](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view) to implement my layout.
It's better than HorizontalView, cause it re-uses views (like ListView).

Answer (score 0):

For cool swiping action viewpager is the best. And you won't have problems with memory. BUT I have no idea how to make view pager part of listview.

Comment: and how can I see adjacent photos (pages) in ViewPager?

Comment: @agamov try making for each image a fragment and show it by viewpager.
OR you can make a gallery. 
Here is some information about horizontal scrollview and listview 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617126/horizontal-listview

Answer (score 0):

If you have final number of items you can use [Android Gallery widget](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) which is deprecated since api 16 but does exactly what you need, the main problem is that it cant reuse gallery items inside the adapter.

You also can try this:
[Horizontal list view](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34)