# Gallery View to move beyond the background of parent

Tags: android, android-gallery

I am working with gallery. 
My layout for the same is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mySelection"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ff0000ff"
    android:textSize="20px"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="#fff785" >

    <Gallery
        android:id="@+id/myGallery"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:spacing="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In this what happens is 
[image: obtained gallery]

But I want it like gallery view should move beyond the background like facebook.
This is the image what i want it to be
[image: expected]

Please suggest what modification can I do to achieve it.

Comment: Broken images - please fix

Comment: I asked the same question some time ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15006150/how-do-i-implement-such-a-layout but no suitable solution was found. Gallery widget is deprecated.

Comment: @agamov :so what did u use to achieve it.?

Comment: actually I am still searching for a solution :). As temporary workaround I am using TwoWayView (https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view) used in Firefox Nightly.

Comment: @agamov : I fount the answer for the same.

Comment: @agamov Did u check the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for the question which I asked above .
I made parent layout as Relative and in that I added Linear Layout with background of what I want. With this i placed Gallery above Linear Layout. And I am able to get what I want to acheive.

layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mySelection"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ff0000ff"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="#fff785"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mySelection" >


</LinearLayout>

<Gallery
        android:id="@+id/myGallery"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:overScrollMode="always"
        android:spacing="10dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```