# Android HorizontalListView which respects wrap_content

Tags: android, android-listview, horizontal-scrolling

I need a horizontal ListView to be in the center of the screen.
And to become scrollable only if content's size is larger than screen's size.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877040/how-can-i-make-a-horizontal-listview-in-android) question

[This lib](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34) is recommended, but when I set width to wrap_content, it ListView behaves like it was set to match_parent. So my items are always on the left edge.

Can anybody give me some advice?